# Git-p4 issues when trying to submit back to perforce

Tags: git, version-control, perforce

So I'm having issues getting this to work properly. I chug along doing a few things in my git repo, commit, git-p4 rebase and git-p4 submit.
The problem pops up on the submit, with the following errors:
`common/data/testsheet2.xls has type 100755, expected 100644`
I get this all over with several different files.
Perforce is set to have all files write-protected. It appears I have to keep it this way in order for the eclipse plugin for Perforce to actually function correctly when I'm dealing with straight perforce repos. Is file permissions my issue here? If so, is there a way to fix this without setting the allwrite option to true on the perforce side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does appear that
`git config core.filemode false`
does the trick.

Comment: And again...I must have a hater out there. This works. No idea why someone is down voting my answers.